# How to run a function after returning 201 view

Tags: python, rest, multithreading, django

I'm using the Django Python framework with the Django REST Framework. When a new instance of a model is saved, I need to generate a PDF that is saved locally on the server. Is there a way that I can branch off the task of generating the PDF so that the user immediately gets a 201 return while the server is generating the PDF? I don't know if this would be a suitable situation for multithreading.

The parent's save function is called before starting the PDF generation so right in between there it would be safe to return 201.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        set_pdf = False
        if self.id is None and self.nda_pdf is not None and len(self.nda_pdf) > 0:
            set_pdf = True
        super(Visitor, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if set_pdf: generate_pdf(self)
```

I want to call that `generate_pdf(self)` function *after* returning something to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much does it take to generate PDF, you may want to block the response until the file is generated and only then return HTTP 201.

It has no influence on multithreading, neither for the client, nor for the server:

- The client should do non-blocking requests any way (or at least do them from a thread different than the one which handles UI events). Moreover, if the client doesn't care about the response (i.e. whether the PDF is generated correctly or not), it's up to the client to send the request without waiting for the response.
- The server... well, the server has to do PDF generation anyway. Returning HTTP 201 immediately won't change anything. Also, the fact that the server is currently responding to one request doesn't mean it won't process another one (unless you have too many requests or use a very weirdly configured HTTP server).

If PDF generation actually takes a long time (say more than a minute), then returning **HTTP 202 Accepted** ([and not HTTP 201!](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273459/6605)) can be a solution in order to avoid timeouts or situations where clients won't understand why the server is not responding for too long.